# Getting data for all available dates in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query that will get the sum of amount from a table for specific month and date and id and gets sum of quantity from another table for same month and date and I am dividing sum of amount of table1  by sum of quantity table2 and multiplied the result with the table2 quantity field and stored result into another field.

Here is my query

```
SELECT RevenueDate, table2.DeliveredQuantity, [CommonUnit(KG)],DeliveryUnit,
    CASE
        WHEN table2.[CommonUnit(KG)] <> 0 
        THEN table2.[CommonUnit(KG)] * ((select SUM(Amount) from dbo.table1 where Ledger ='100' AND MONTH(FiscalDate) = 4 AND YEAR(FiscalDate)=2023 )  / (SELECT SUM([CommonUnit(KG)]) FROM dbo.table2 WHERE MONTH(RevenueDate) = 4 AND YEAR(RevenueDate) = 2023))
    END AS newcolumn
FROM
    dbo.table2 WHERE MONTH(RevenueDate) = 4 AND YEAR(RevenueDate) = 2023;
```

In the above query I have done for a specific month and year how to do for all dates available in fiscaldate column in table1?

```
Table1
fiscaldate|Ledger|Amount
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|100|1000
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|100|500
2023-05-13 06:58:52.000|100|600
2023-05-13 06:58:52.000|100|800

Table2
RevenueDate|CommonUnit(KG)
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|10
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|5
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|10
2023-05-15 06:58:52.000|50

output:
RevenueDate|CommonUnit(KG)|NewColumn
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|10|600
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|5|300
2023-04-13 06:58:52.000|10|600
2023-05-15 06:58:52.000|50|1400
```

Comment: With a database, when you say you "stored the result into another field", that has a specific meaning that is not at all related to what you are doing here. Instead, that would imply an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

Comment: i am creating view with that query

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results so we can see clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i've edited my question with example

Comment: A view is still not storing data. Even if it's an indexed/materialized view that's strange phrasing when talking about a SELECT query. More correct would be to say you "project the result into another column".

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the subqueries to the outer table. Exactly how you should do that I don't know, because I don't know what your data is, but you probably want something like `t1.FiscalDate = t2.RevenueDate`.

- The two subqueries can be combined by using an `APPLY`.
- The `CASE` can be replace by `NULLIF`.
- The date checks should use ranges `>= AND <` rather than functions, in order to be able to use indexes.

```sql
SELECT
  t2.RevenueDate,
  t2.DeliveredQuantity,
  t2.[CommonUnit(KG)],
  t2.DeliveryUnit,
  NULLIF(t2.[CommonUnit(KG)] * (t1.Amount / t1.[CommonUnit(KG)]), 0) AS newcolumn
FROM
    dbo.table2 t2
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
      SUM([CommonUnit(KG)]) AS [CommonUnit(KG)]
    FROM dbo.table1 t1
    WHERE t1.Ledger = '100'
      AND t1.FiscalDate = t2.RevenueDate
) t1
WHERE t2.RevenueDate >= '20230401'
  AND t2.RevenueDate  < '20230501';
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the sum of amount from table1 and sum of quantity
from table2 for all dates available in the fiscaldate column in table1 and multiply the result with the table2 quantity field and stored result into another field. You can just **modify the query by removing the specific month and year filter**.

The query goes like

```
SELECT RevenueDate, table2.DeliveredQuantity, [CommonUnit(KG)], DeliveryUnit,
CASE
    WHEN table2.[CommonUnit(KG)] <> 0 
    THEN table2.[CommonUnit(KG)] * ((
        SELECT SUM(Amount)
        FROM dbo.table1
        WHERE Ledger ='100' AND table1.FiscalDate = table2.RevenueDate  / (
        SELECT SUM([CommonUnit(KG)])
        FROM dbo.table2
        WHERE table2.RevenueDate = table2.RevenueDate)
    )
END AS newcolumn
FROM dbo.table2
```